I need suggestion for a project
I want to make a forecasting system which will forecast how much quantity will be sold next year based on the previous 5 years' data from 2019 to 2023 and want to predict for future years. Now the problem is my data contains product name product category quantity and date but in the form of Jan, Feb and march not the start or end date. But I'm struck on what to do if I make separate models for each product which isn't suitable at the industry level I have 40 plus products so that's not suitable. My product name and category name is repeated like product  A, category A, the date for example Jan 2019, quantity 60, then feb 2019 product A, category A quantity 70 this way. So, I need suggestions on what can I do about it.
I tried using LSTM but it only does for 1 product which isnt suitable. I even tried regression but the problem is I want to see results based on the product name I give and the year I want. So, it doesn't work with it.

You can just use a single date like the beginning or end of the month to represent each month value. An example of this is done here: Catfish Monthly Sales Prediction
I'm not sure how to to model multiple products but I'm interested in this as well so I'm following your question!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
